# How to run cron script alternately 30 minutes every minute

Tags: cron

I have two web servers namely web1 and web2. They are identical servers. Now, I have a php script that needs to run every 30 minutes. How can I run the php script in alternately every 30 minutes. Let say after 30 minutes from web1 server, the next 30 minutes will be run to web2 server.

This is wrong.

`web1:
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/site/cron.php


web2:
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/site/cron.php`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Either put the smarts in your script and just trigger the script every 30 mins

(e.g. save a file telling it which server it ran on last time)

OR

Run on web1 when the minute is 00, run on web2 when the minute is 30.

> # min hr dom moy dow
>
> 0   *  *   *   *   web1
>
> 30  *  *   *   *   web2

Comment: Right, that's what Im following now and it's really working.
How can I make my cron to log all cron scripts that if it is succeeded or not. Just like in Task scheduler in Windows like this http://bit.ly/GCyo6v. Thanks

Comment: I'd make the script output to a file. I don't recall any OS level "cron logging".

Comment: Hi John, would appreciate if you could share your script. Thanks

Comment: I don't actually have one. Basically all you need is your script to write a file e.g. start timestamp, any diagnostics and end timestamp - if the end timestamp is missing, you know it failed (but hopefully the diagnostics between the start and end let you figure out why ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Schedule it manually on each web server to run every 1 hour i.e. schedule your cron on web1 
to run at 00:00 , 01:00 , 02:00 ..... 23:00 and your cron on web2 to run at 00:30 , 01:30 , 02:30 ......23:30 ( You need to put manual entry for each run )